# ListView not updating (c#)

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am doing a simple test because I need to learn about the ListView. I've done a lot of searching and there is a LOT out there but all of it trying to do more than just the basics. So to understand the concept I've done a simple program and listed it below.

Everything works - except when i rotate the phone. I understand that it will destroy the Activity and I need to re-create the listview and adapter.
What I don't understand is - why my list of strings is also "destroyed".

Looking at my example - the weekdays will be there after rotation. But the list of click-times will not !! 
What would be the right way to use the listview in my case? I'm not trying to do complicated row views or custom adapters. I'll go with the basics.
Thanks !

```
namespace NewListViewTest
{
    [Activity(Label = "NewListViewTest", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Button StartScan;
        Button StopScan;
        TextView Filter;
        ListView IBeaconActivities;
        List<string> dataList;
        ArrayAdapter<string> dataAdapter;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            dataList = new List<string>();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();
            StartScan = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.startScan);
            StartScan.Click += StartScan_Click;

            StopScan = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.stopScan);
            Filter = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.filter);
            IBeaconActivities = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.beaconActivities);

            dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, dataList);
            IBeaconActivities.Adapter = dataAdapter;

            dataList.Add("Monday");
            dataList.Add("Tuesday");
            dataList.Add("Wednesday");
            dataList.Add("Thursday");
            dataList.Add("Friday");
            dataList.Add("Saturday");
            dataList.Add("Sunday");

            DataWasUpdated();
        }

        public void DataWasUpdated()
        {
            dataAdapter.Clear();
            dataAdapter.AddAll(dataList);

            dataAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private void StartScan_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            dataList.Add("New item at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
            DataWasUpdated();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried OnResume method?

Comment: The days of the week will still be there as onStart is called when you rotate; you need to save the new items in `onSaveInstanceState`. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#tba the "Saving and restoring activity state" section

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. There is a LOT of other interesting things there to be learned I can see. Also the model view-model view "stuff" is of interest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ListView not updating (c#)

You could read the  [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#alc) document, when you rotate the phone, your `Activity` will be destroyed and recreate. You could add a log to see more information, for example  :

```
protected override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();
    Log.Error(Tag, "OnPause");
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    Log.Error(Tag, "OnResume");
}

protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.Error(Tag, "OnSaveInstanceState");
}

protected override void OnRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.Error(Tag, "OnRestoreInstanceState");
}

protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    Log.Error(Tag, "OnDestroy");
}

......
```

When you rotate your phone, you could see following information :

[image]

That's why your `ListView` will be destroyed.

### Solution :

Add a [ConfigurationChanges](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) attribute in your `Activity` :

```
[Activity(Label = "ListActivity", 
    ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
public class ListActivity : Activity
```

Then, when you rotate your phone only execute the `OnConfigurationChanged` method :

```
E/Activity (17410): OnConfigurationChanged
```

Your `Activity` won't be created and your `New item` will still exist.

Comment: It will do the trick, so I marked your answer as the solution. Also nice that you put in some background info instead of simply providing the answer. Thanks!